# Materalize footer doesn't stay at bottom?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Im using materialize for my webpage, and for some reason the footer won't stay at the bottom even though I use Materialize own recommended CSS for this. Am I missing something?

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

And here's the HTML for the footer:

```
<footer class="page-footer green lighten-1">
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!--   Icon Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="green-text" id="mailIcon"><i class="material-icons">mail</i></h4>
            <p class="white-text">info@storytourist.com</p>
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="green-text" id="adressIcon"><i class="material-icons">map</i></h4>
            <p>Veldrom AB, Anckargripsgatan 3, 211 19 Malmö, Sweden</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="green-text" id="phoneIcon"><i class="material-icons">phone</i></h4>
            <p class="white-text">+46 720 427 346</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Check that your body / any other parents to the footer do not have any margin or padding. That one usually gets me.

Comment: do you have `body` and `main` tag??

Comment: @MichaelThompson I don't have anything like that. It's wierd, other pages with more content keeps the footer at the bottom, for pages with less information (i guess less than screen height) it's like its too small in height for the footer to be kept at bottom.

Comment: Aaahhh, yes. I have seen this before. You want it to stick to the bottom of the viewpane irrespecive of scrolling and content, am I correct? Also, If you add more content, does your footer move to the bottom?

Comment: That is correct, I want the footer to always stay at bottom, and if there where to be more content, the footer would follow along and you'd have to scroll down the page to see the footer. I think we understand each other.

Comment: I myself have done this before, on my own personal site, also using Materialize. I have used CSS similar to yours and when I use exactly yours, it works on my site. Are you able to post a jsfiddle for me to play with please?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM SOLVED.**

Didn't use a main tag.

```
<body>

  <main>  //added 
     <div class="container">
     </div>
  </main>

  <footer> this is my footer </footer>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **sticking your footer to the botton** add this to your css:

```
.page-footer{
    position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

**The Complete CSS will be:**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


.page-footer{
    position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

---

### [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer)